# I'm getting some error messages on add field 'type_login' in php script

Tags: php

I want to add one field "type_login" than I'm getting some error messages
PHP script. missing code please help me...

**error ->**

**Warning:  mysqli_stmt_bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in D:\xammp\htdocs\raisebux\admin\member-register.php on line 85**

**line no. 85**

> mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $param_username, $param_password,
>   $param_type);

**table login**

> insert in a table data this type

```
user_id | username | password | type_login
     1  | abcd     | xxxxxxxx |        1
     2  | avcd     | xxxxxxxx |        2
     3  | hbcd     | xxxxxxxx |        3
```

**PHP insert script here...**

> ```
> if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
>
>     if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
>         $username_err = "Please enter a username.";
>     } else{
>         $sql = "SELECT user_id FROM  login WHERE username = ?";
>
>         if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql)){
>             mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);
>
>             $param_username = trim($_POST["username"]);
>
>             if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
>                 mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
>
>                 if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){
>                     $username_err = "This username is already taken.";
>                 } else{
>                     $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
>                 }
>             } else{
>                 echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
>             }
>         }
>
>         mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
>     }
>   //------------------------
>   if(empty(trim($_POST["type_login"]))){
>         $type_login_err = "Select User Type.";
>     } else{
>         $sql = "SELECT type_login FROM  login WHERE type_login = ?";
>
>         if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql)){
>             mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_type);
>
>             $param_type = trim($_POST["type_login"]);
>
>
>         }
>
>         mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
>     }
>
>
>
>     //------------------------
>     if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
>         $password_err = "Please enter a password.";     
>     } elseif(strlen(trim($_POST["password"])) < 6){
>         $password_err = "Password must have atleast 6 characters.";
>     } else{
>         $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
>     }
>
>     if(empty(trim($_POST["confirm_password"]))){
>         $confirm_password_err = "Please confirm password.";     
>     } else{
>         $confirm_password = trim($_POST["confirm_password"]);
>         if(empty($password_err) && ($password != $confirm_password)){
>             $confirm_password_err = "Password did not match.";
>         }
>     }
>
>
>
>     if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err) && empty($confirm_password_err) && empty($type_login_err)){
>
>         $sql = "INSERT INTO login (username, password, type_login) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
>
>         if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql)){
>             mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $param_username, $param_password, $param_type);
>
>             $param_username = $username;
>           $param_type = $type_login;
>             $param_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); 
>
>             if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
>                 header("location: sign-in.php");
>             } else{
>                 echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
>             }
>         }
>         mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
>     }
>     mysqli_close($conn);
> }
> ?>
> ```

**html form here**

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">

        <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">

            <label>Username</label>

            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">

            <span class="help-block"><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>

        </div>

        <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">

            <label>Password</label>

            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $password; ?>">

            <span class="help-block"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>

        </div>

        <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($confirm_password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">

            <label>Confirm Password</label>

            <input type="password" name="confirm_password" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $confirm_password; ?>">

            <span class="help-block"><?php echo $confirm_password_err; ?></span>

        </div>

        <div class="form-group<?php echo (!empty($type_login_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">

            <label>Select User Type</label>

            <select  name="type_login"  class="form-control"  required>

               <option value="">Select</option>

               <option value="1">SuperAdmin</option>

               <option value="2">Admin</option>

               <option value="3">User</option>

            </select>

           <span class="help-block"><?php echo $type_login_err; ?></span>

     </div>                                                                     
      <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
            <input type="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Reset">
      </div>                                    
    </form>
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **web development** which is off-topic at Pro Webmasters. Web development questions may be asked at [so] but be sure to read their [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before posting to ensure your question meets their guidelines. In its current form, this question does *not* meet their guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $param_username, $param_password, $param_type);
> ```

You are only defining 2 bind variable types `s` and `s` in the type definition string `"ss"` (2nd argument), but you are passing 3 bind variables (`$param_username`, `$param_password` and `$param_type`) in the following function arguments, hence the error: "Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables".

You need to pass 3 variable types, corresponding to the 3 bind variables, depending on the data types of those columns. If it's another string then `"sss"`, however, it looks like an integer, so maybe `"ssi"`.

Reference:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php